# How to ignore the parent's padding using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a simplified of my DOM structure:

```css
.page{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent{
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.header{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="header">this needs to ignore its parent padding</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I want to do is, the red-bordered element ignores the blue-bordered element's `padding`. How can I do that? In another word, the red one must be stick to the blue one from the top, left and right.

Noted that, I cannot change the HTML whatsoever.

Comment: Would something like `position: relative;` on the parent, and `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` (depending on what you mean by “left and right”) be acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use negative margin

```css
.page{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent{
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.header{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin:-50px -50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="header">this needs to ignore its parent padding</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the `.parent` relative position, then give the header absolute position with `top` and `left` set to zero.

```css
.page{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent{
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.header{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="header">this needs to ignore its parent padding</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
      <p>some paragraphs</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The header needs to have negative margins and lose the 100% width:

```
.header{
  margin: -50px -50px 0 -50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: this is exactly my answer

Comment: Sorry mate I didn't copy paste yours. I was working on it on JSBin before directly posted here.

Comment: I never said you copied mine, I simply said that my answer already covered the same

Comment: Then let it be.